# How do I change the default tab bar item in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    println("TabBar viewDidAppear")
    self.checkForNewKey()
    if freshLaunch == true {
        freshLaunch = false
        self.tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![2] as? UITabBarItem
    }
}
```

I did this...but the entire app crashes (not sure why). I have 5 items in my tab bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use     `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2`

instead of `self.tabBar`

Comment: this is your tabbarcontroller?

Comment: Yes. TabBarcontroller